# How to update commited message in git without using text editor?

Tags: git

There are 2 ways to update commited message in git:

a) git commit --amend (it will open text editor and you will be able to update the existing message by Change ID)

**How can i update the message without using text editor?**

-if i use 'git commit --amend -m "updated message"' (it is creating new change...)

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `-m` option as you would when making a normal commit:

```
git commit --amend -m "updated message"
```

**Note:**

Amending a commit in Git *always* results in a *new* commit being created.  The old commit will still be there, in the reflog, for some time.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Commit is identified by its hash. The hash is computed from all the data, including the commit message. Changing the commit message changes the hash and that results in new commit.

Comment: Is there a way to make change in the commit message without creating new change (if it is already pushed to Gerrit)?

Comment: Not AFAIK.  When you amend a commit you change the history of that branch.