# How can I append a line to a git commit message from the command line?

Tags: git

I'd like to *append* (leaving the rest of the commit message intact) a line to my last commit from the command line (ie without having to open my editor).  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update commited message in git without using text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789778/how-to-update-commited-message-in-git-without-using-text-editor)

Comment: @mkrieger1 The answer to that would *replace* the commit message, not append to it.

Comment: Obviously one would need to enter the new commit message *including* the existing one.

Comment: That's not really feasible if you have a significant commit message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example commit:

```
git commit -m 'foo'
#foo
```

Appending the string *bar*:

```
git commit --amend -m "$(git log --format=%B -n 1) bar"
#foo bar
```